# Adding buttons to gtk box (gtk 3) in horizontal mode, widget consumes entire vertical space eventhoug expand is set to false

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

As given in the documentation I set the expand property to false and also the fill property to false like gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(box1), button, FALSE, FALSE, 0); It works properly in horizontal direction by occupying only the required space, but vertically it fills the entire screen area. How to get around this?[image]

Comment: Please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you're using GTK+ 3, you might want to switch to [GtkGrid](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s02.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you @liberforce will try the same, but I though the box layout might have some functionalities too, which I will try too

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do so by putting the horizontal box in to another vertical box, which capped it to required height.

[image]